# Why does Naive Forecast,Moving average,Simple Exponential Smothing model predictions flatten?

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, statistics

I have applied simple forecasting models such as Naive Forecast, Moving Average, Simple Exponential Smoothing, Holts Linear Trend Model on 2018 sales data of a salesperson.

All the model resulted in flatten or prediction line flattens at zero. Could be it be an issue with data? as most of the data is flatten at zero.

[image: ARIMA Fitted plot]
[image]

[image]
[image: Difference between given and predict data sets]

```
model = ARIMA(train_log, order=(0, 1, 2))  
output = model.fit(disp=-1)  

#convert fitted values in to series
output_series=pd.Series(output.fittedvalues, copy=True) 
print(output_series.head())

#Calc Cumm sum
output_series_cumsum= output_series.cumsum()
print(output_series.head())

#Add cumsum values
output_tr_log=pd.Series(train_log.ix[0],index=train_log.index)
output_tr_log=output_tr_log.add(output_series_cumsum,fill_value=0)
output_tr_log.head()

#convert to predicted ARIMA vlaues to original format 
convert_output = np.exp(output_tr_log)
plt.title('RMSE: %.4f'% (np.sqrt(np.dot(convert_output, train_log))/len(train_log))
```

```
Date       Sales
----       -----
2018-01-27  1
2018-01-30  60
2018-01-31  22
2018-02-01  490
2018-02-04  53
2018-02-05  30
2018-02-06  204
2018-02-07  234
2018-02-08  64
2018-02-10  70
2018-02-11  81
2018-02-12  10
2018-06-01  40
2018-06-02  669
2018-06-06  1188
2018-06-07  1250
2018-06-10  3861
2018-06-14  40
2018-06-21  44
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive forecast = random walk with no drift will always give a flat straight line as your forecasts. This is just the last observed data point in your time series extended forward n steps ahead.

The moving average model with m =50 will be the average of the most 50 recent data points. As we can see, your time series is mostly flat with some erratic peaks that have been smoothed away by the relatively large window (50) that you have chosen. In general, the larger the window the more flat and smooth your forecasts. Try changing the window to be smaller and you will probably get more erratic behavior in your forecasts.

Simple exponential smoothing always gives a flat forecast since all forecasted values are equal to the first forecasted value (i.e. y(t+k) = y(t+k-1) =....y(t+1), for all k > 1). This can be proven quite easily using basic induction.

Holts Linear Trend model breaks up the forecasts into three different components; the trend, level, and seasonality. If your time series exhibits no seasonality and no level changes then all you will be left with is your trend which is a flat line in your case.

Your time series looks to be a flat line with unpredictable random fluctuations. Hence, in terms of forecasting error I am not too surprised to see that a flat line may give the best forecasts. Try calculating RMSE, MAE, or MASE (which compares to the naive method directly) and see for yourself. Often, a flat line is the best forecast especially for financial time series in particular.

Comment: aranglol -sure will try out those options. Before that need one clarification.As my TS data is a flat line with random fluctuations. So can it can be called has a trend or cyclicity type of Time series data?

Comment: Cyclical, I think. This is sales data, right? I would think that there would be consistent cyclical patterns. Namely, what do you think is causing the spikes at June, and the last quarter of the year? June, maybe a sale/start of summer? Last quarter of the year, maybe the holiday season? You could add exogenous variables to time series models that support them that account for this.

Comment: In other words, an ARMA model could be useful if you believe that certain patterns shluld be consistent year to year.

Comment: aranglol-yes its sales data, all your predictions are absolutely right. Have tried the ARIMA model,infact am a bit confused on values to be passed ARIMA predict function, specifically on start & end fields. Tried prediction function with test data set range got a slicing error, posted in SO[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240139/] no reply yet.So,then i treid by taking lenght of train data set range and it worked, but having trouble interpreting the graphs. Have attached screen shots, please suggest.

Comment: Also,I see nan's populated(excpet coef column) in these fields  "ar.L2.D.Volume","ma.L1.D.Volume" and "ma.L2.D.Volume"  ARIMA model results summary.what could be the reason?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the answer for your programming problem as I mostly do my time series stuff in R (though I really should get better at Python). I hope someone else is able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Will wait for other answers

Comment: aranglol, i have tried ARMA(data, order=(0,1)) however got huge differences between actuals and predictions. Looks like have not feed input parameters correctly, can you help me on this? also tried ARMA order values as (1,1) but got a value error as `The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary
You should induce stationarity, choose a different model order`.So, tried ARMA with order(0,1) and it worked but results not good.As i see spikes in June and a decemmber month, so is this correct way of feeding exog variables exog =[6,12] ?Any references of ARMA implementation helpful?

Comment: All right, I haven't seen your code so I can't comment on if the values are put in correctly (and as I stated before, I don't know how time series work in Python). That being said, with stationarity, basically your fitted models coefficients are yielding a nonstationary ARMA model. This means that there exists solutions to the fitted equation representing the process that lie (numerically) on the unit circle. This isn't necessarily a huge problem, but it often leads to potentially unstable predictions/large prediction intervals.

Comment: In R at least, with exogenous variables you set up these variables in a data frame. Note that these exogenous variables are time series themselves (they take values at specified time intervals), but they typically are just 0/1 indicators. Every column/time series is a separate exogenous variable and is a 0/1 indicator variable, typically, for time related events. For instance, you state that you see spikes in June and December months. Then for your June variable, you place a 1 for every time your time series is in "June", and 0 otherwise. For...

Comment: December, you do the same by placing a 1 for every time your time series is in "December", and 0 otherwise. These two columns (which are really just time series themselves) are held in a data frame and then this frame is then sent to the exog argument. Again, this is how it is done in R. I imagine this is similar in Python. To further illustrate the example, imagine you have a time series of sales for June, July, August, September, October, November, and December of (400,100,100,200,200,300, 600)...

Comment: Then your June exogenous variable/time series would be (1,0,0,0,0,0,0), and your December exogenous variable/time series would be (0,0,0,0,0,0,1). Basically, these columns become "active" = 1 when your modeled time series (sales) is in the corresponding month. You can see now how stuff like seasonality can be modeled through exogenous variables as well, using indicators but also through Fourier transforms, for example. Sales, trend shifts, etc. can also be modeled as indicators as well in exactly the same way.

Comment: My TS values were captured by day wise- 149 days and as mentioned in earlier comment spikes were seen in June & December month days. The numbers were generated random days in June and can't group them by month to get a single value which reduces the data points to 12.In this case,do i have to set 1 for every value in june & december ? sample code attached and data updated.

Comment: Another observation from the ARIMA model,log-transformed values(from train set) match with predicted values, however, actual & predicted values see huge differences. Even after taking np.exp(), do see huge differences in predictions.

Comment: All right, I'll take a look into your data and update my post. However, note that although your time series is by the day, there is a month attached to each data point still. For example, if we had a exogenous variable that indicated month "July", and a time series with points (June 28/2005, June 29/2005, June 30/2005, July 1st/2005, July 2nd/2005) the exogenous variable would look like (0,0,0,1,1). I am not suggesting to aggregate your series to months, rather, I am suggesting to indicate by the month (or the day, or the week, this is all up to you)...

Comment: sure, will try on that.